# Add one more StructField to schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My PySpark data frame has the following schema:

```
schema = spark_df.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- field_1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field_2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field_3 (nullable = true)
 |-- field_4: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field_5: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field_6: double (nullable = true)
```

I would like to add one more StructField to the schema, so the new schema would looks like:

```
root
 |-- field_1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field_1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field_2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field_3 (nullable = true)
 |-- field_4: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field_5: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field_6: double (nullable = true)
```

I know I can manually create a new_schema like below:

```
new_schema = StructType([StructField("field_0", StringType(), True),
                            :
                         StructField("field_6", IntegerType(), True)])
```

This works for a small number of fields but couldn't generate if I have hundreds of fields. So I am wondering is there a more elegant way to add a new field to the beginning of the schema? Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can copy existing fields and perpend:

```
to_prepend = [StructField("field_0", StringType(), True)] 

StructType(to_prepend + df.schema.fields)
```

Comment: I got the following error:  
----> 5 StructType(to_prepend + schema.fields)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: I mean if schema is really a schema. You execute `spark_df.printSchema()` which doesn't return useful value.

Comment: in case you may need to prepend more than one field, you could also use the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959493/creating-spark-schema-for-glove-word-vector-files/50650639#50650639

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to ask how to prepend a field to a schema, but please note that if you just want to add a field then this can be achieved with the `StructType.add(field)` method. Eg.:

```
#define some schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField('Field 1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('Field 2', StringType(), True)
])
#add a field
schema.add('Field 3', StringType(), True)

#create empty dataframe from schema and test
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[], schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
```